# Get matching rows between two tables and NULL otherwise on left table

Tags: mysql, join

I have a MySQL `sponsors` table containing sponsors data, and a `magazine_sponsors` table saying which sponsors are linked to a specific magazine.

```
sponsors
-------------------------
| id     | name         |
-------------------------
| sponA  | Sponsor A    |
| sponB  | Sponsor B    |
| sponC  | Sponsor C    |
-------------------------

magazine_sponsors
----------------------------
| magazine_id | sponsor_id |
----------------------------
| magA        | sponA      |
| magA        | sponB      |
| magB        | sponA      |
----------------------------
```

My goal is to display, given a specific `magazine_id`, the complete list of available sponsors, saying which of them are linked to the magazine and which are not. For example, with `magB` I would like to get:

```
----------------------------------------
| magazine_id | sponsor_id | name      |
----------------------------------------
| magB        | sponA      | Sponsor A |
| NULL        | sponB      | Sponsor B |
| NULL        | sponC      | Sponsor C |
----------------------------------------
```

I've tried the following query using `RIGHT JOIN`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM magazine_sponsors ms 
RIGHT JOIN sponsors s ON ms.sponsor_id=s.id 
WHERE ms.magazine_id="magB"
```

but it only outputs the first row.

```
----------------------------------------
| magazine_id | sponsor_id | name      |
----------------------------------------
| magB        | sponA      | Sponsor A |
----------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition in your `WHERE` is converting your OUTER JOIN to an INNER ONE. You either need to add `OR ms.magazine_id IS NULL` to your condition or move it to the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sponsors s 
LEFT JOIN magazine_sponsors ms ON ms.sponsor_id=s.id AND ms.magazine_id="magB"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM magazine_sponsors ms 
LEFT JOIN sponsors s ON ms.sponsor_id=s.id 
WHERE ms.magazine_id="magB"
```

Comment: It returns only the row with "magB". Thanks anyway.